# Linux kernel update stuck

Tags: kernel, ubuntu-gnome, 17.04

I just installed a new kernel on Ubuntu GNOME 17.04 that came in through the normal updates. However, it is now stuck for a while on the following line:

```
Setting up linux-headers-4.10.0-20-generic (4.10.0-20.22) ...
Examining /etc/kernel/header_postinst.d.
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/header_postinst.d/dkms 4.10.0-20-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.10.0-20-generic
```

Something seems to hang the process. Does someone know what could cause this?

EDIT: This is the content of /boot as requested:

```
abi-4.10.0-19-generic     grub                          System.map-4.10.0-19-generic
abi-4.10.0-20-generic     initrd.img-4.10.0-19-generic  System.map-4.10.0-20-generic
config-4.10.0-19-generic  memtest86+.bin                vmlinuz-4.10.0-19-generic
config-4.10.0-20-generic  memtest86+.elf                vmlinuz-4.10.0-19-generic.efi.signed
efi                       memtest86+_multiboot.bin      vmlinuz-4.10.0-20-generic
```

EDIT 2: Just tried purging the new kernel but got this:

```
E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem.
```

Using that command returns me to the original problem. I am stuck now :(

Comment: You use graphical update-manager for this? Or commandline and apt?

Comment: Both. I first tried the graphical updater, but when I noticed it stuck I tried the command line. Same result (and output) however..

Comment: Please post `ls /boot/`

Comment: @davidbaumann See my question edit for the output :)

Comment: If DKMS build kernel failed, it will leave the make.log for you to tell what happened.
The log will be at /var/lib/dkms/<your_module_name>/<your_module_version>/build/make.log

Comment: Thanks for the answers ,@davidbaumann ! Looking in the folders, I have 3 modules: bbswitch, nvidia-735 and virtualbox. But I only have a `kernel-4.10.0-19-generic-x86_64` folder in all of them (which is the previous version, the kernel version it tries to install is 4.10.0-20). So it seems it doesn't even attempts to build any module..

Comment: `apt remove --purge` and reinstall afterwards might help. But I don't know if package manager will be confused for future kernel updates afterwards.

Comment: @davidbaumann Do you mean uninstalling and reïnstalling the failing kernel? (4.10.0-20)

Comment: Purging also doesn't work. (see edit #2) I think I'm going to file a bug for this...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just "fixed" it. I was running Ubuntu with my Nvidia Graphics card all the time. I switched back to the build-in Intel graphics with the Nvidia Control Center and rebooted. After this, the configuration of the kernel didn't hang and everything seems to work as normal.

So if you also have this issue, try to change back to Intel graphics before running `dpkg --configure -a`

Comment: This also worked for me. For those coming to this answer, I ended up trying to perform this dist-upgrade because the gnome apps kept failing to open with an exit code of 139 and constantly reporting VMA errors.