# Ubuntu 17.10 Update hangs

Tags: updates, dpkg, 17.10

I have a problem similar to the questions below:

[Linux kernel update stuck](https://askubuntu.com/questions/908676/linux-kernel-update-stuck)
[Apt install hanging/Freezes when trying to run updates with no errors 17.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/979335/apt-install-hanging-freezes-when-trying-to-run-updates-with-no-errors-17-10)

Example:

> $ sudo dpkg --configure -a
>   linux-headers-4.13.0-17-generic (4.13.0-17.20) wird eingerichtet ...
>   Examining /etc/kernel/header_postinst.d.
>   run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/header_postinst.d/dkms 4.13.0-17-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.13.0-17-generic

After that, no more progress.

The solution to the questions linked above was to switch to the Nouveau driver.
However, even though I have a NVIDIA GTX670M, the Nouveau driver is already enabled! At least this is what the GUI for the proprietory drivers tells me...

Any ideas on how to resolve this?

Comment: Neither removal of DKMS modules nor repair of packages via recovery console nor partial update via gui nor tinkering with various apt-get commands helped.   Therefore my patience wore out and I just reinstalled 17.10. Now everything works fine.